# PHP PDO - Change time in a table to Unix without updating the original row

Tags: php, mysql

I have a PDO table that contains a column called 'creation_time'. This is created automatically when a new row is created and has the following layout - 2014-05-09 18:21:18

I have around 20 records. I'd in a particular query I'd like to convert the time 'creation_time' to unix in PHP without actually updating the row.

This is what I tried till now.
$today value is already in Unix

```
$stmt = $dbh->prepare("SELECT * FROM $table WHERE strtotime(create_date) > :today  ORDER BY id DESC");
$stmt->bindValue(':today', $today, PDO::PARAM_STR);
$stmt->execute();
while ($result = $stmt->fetch()) {
//Display values
//Display values
//Display values
}
```

How can I get the unix time of create_date without updating the value, please? I know that I can create another row with a unix time but I want to avoid that option.

Comment: Strtotime in an SQL statement? Believe you're looking for `UNIX_TIMESTAMP`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`str_to_time()` is a  PHP function so you can't use it in your SQL. You will need to use MySQL's [`UNIX_TIMESTAMP()`](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.1/en/date-and-time-functions.html#function_unix-timestamp):

```
 SELECT * FROM $table WHERE UNIX_TIMESTAMP(create_date) > :today  ORDER BY id DESC
```

Answer (score 0):

> I'd in a particular query I'd like to convert the time 'creation_time' to unix

You don't need it.

Just compare your date column with date value without no unix timestamps

Comment: Because you don't need it